# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns image with greater size than the original

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am new to Android programming. I was trying to display an image from my device's sd card onto an `ImageView`, using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)`. I can read the image fine from sd card, followed the [official documentation to loading bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Although one thing I cannot understand is why the bitmap returned is much greater in size than the original size? Original image size was 84.32 kb, the bitmap that I got was of the size 4.096 mb. I was trying to load the bitmap with the height and width of the image, i.e. 1280x800. If I reduce the width and height of the image in the method below , I get reduced size. But why I can't load the image in bitmap with its original size and actual width and height?

Method decodeSampledBitmap():

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String path,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    //return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: "Original image size was 84.32 kb" -- how are you determining this? For example, is this the size of the image on disk? "the bitmap that I got was of the size 4.096 mb" -- how are you determining this?

Comment: yes the size on the disk was of 84.32 kb and the size of the bitmap I got was with: bitmap.getByteCount() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the image on disk has little to do with the size of the image in memory. PNG, JPEG, and GIF images are compressed on disk. In memory, they are uncompressed.

Comment: So that means to get the bitmap of reasonable size, I do have to reduce its width and height? Then how do I place it in an imageview that occupies 50% of the screen(for e.g.)? If I set the Imageview width and height then it will stretch the bitmap image

Comment: Use 'scaleType' for ImageView.

Comment: @user3052023: Um, "50% of the screen" only infrequently will match the original dimensions of the image. Also, bear in mind that there are several thousand Android device models, with varying screen resolutions. Hence, you would have your same issue even if you were to load the image with an `inSampleSize` of `1`. As sonngaytho notes, use `android:scaleType` on your `ImageView` to control how the image gets loaded into it, when the image dimensions and the `ImageView` dimensions are not the same.